# When I am fitting a model it does not show the hyperparameters after the model is created

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I do not get the hyperparameters displayed when I run the following command.

[image: Code]

Comment: As you see you are not passing any hyperparameters by yourself, so default ones are used and you can check about them in the documentation. `scikit learn` doesn't show hyperparameters, as the ones you set by yourself are in function declaration that you make, and rest are by default.

Answer (score 1):

To print the parameter use get_prams command

Example like:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
Knn=KNeighborsClassifier()
Knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(Knn.get_params())
```

output will be:

```
{'algorithm': 'auto', 'leaf_size': 30, 'metric': 'minkowski', 'metric_params': None, 'n_jobs': None, 'n_neighbors': 5, 'p': 2, 'weights': 'uniform'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve